# How do you prevent access to a mutually accessible variable?

Tags: objective-c, c, multithreading

I have a function that accepts an integer pointer as an argument, which it then alters. I have several instances of the function running on separate threads - some that have the same integer as the argument.

I need to pause the instance of the function if the argument is being altered by another instance of the function on another thread and resume when the other instance has completed altering the variable.

The seemingly obvious solution that to this kind of problem would be an NSLock or a POSIX mutex, however this would prevent *all* instances of the function from continuing, even if the  integer argument is different.

For a more intuitive idea of what I mean consider the following:

```
void theFunction (int *argument)
{   
    NSLock *theLock = [NSLock new];
    [theLock lock];

    (*argument) ++;

    [theLock unlock];
}
```

The above code would prevent *all* instances of the function from running, however I only need to pause the instances of the function where the integer argument is the *same*. How can I lock the variable specifically, as to pause any instances attempting to read or write to it until it is unlocked?

Comment: How many different values will this integer variable have?

Comment: OK, the edit makes this question make more sense, but your operator precedence in `*argument ++` is wrong (and the space is misleading).

Comment: After your edit, I had to delete my answer, since things are not as simple as I'd hoped for. The issue with the local lock remains. Is it really meaningful to grant access based on the value of `*argument` instead of the address `argument` (as ISTM it's the location being pointed to, which is the protection-worthy resource)? Maybe, you should provide more context here.

Comment: Yes, more context needed. Is it ok to wrap the integer object so that the function accepts a pointer to a (object, lock) tuple? Is the operation something that can be done via atomic operations? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the int*, consider using the atomic increment operation (see man on OSAtomicAdd32). It's pretty cheap to per-value locking that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate lock for each argument?